# Decoding SCT extension in X.509 certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, cryptography, x509, asn.1

Im currently trying create some code to decode the SCT extension in a X.509 Certificate (OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2). It has mostly been successful, however the SCT signature turns out wrong for me when comparing my result to OpenSSL. An example:

Mine:
37:F6:....:E2:16:....

OpenSSL:
**30:45:02:20**:37:F6:....:**02:21:00**:E2:16:....

To clarify the "...." are the same for both. For all my test cases, the same pattern of:
**30:45:02:20** and **02:21:00** come up. When trying to interpret these additional octets my guess is that these represent: 0x30 -> SEQUENCE and 0x02 -> INTEGER and the following octets represents length etc. Should these be included in the signature or is there something i have missed?

Comment: Presumably this is an ECDSA signature represented as a DER encoded ECDSA-Sig-Value from appendix C.5 of http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf

Comment: This is a ASN.1 extention whose value is a TLS-encoded SCT. See https://letsencrypt.org/2018/04/04/sct-encoding.html for more details.